# imaging/cloning with DHCP network rebuilding/recovery of solaris 9 and 10 sparc servers

Tags: solaris

I have a number of Solaris 9 and 10 sparc servers (no RAID) that are custom DVD jumpstarts provided by SONUS Networks for their softswitch VOIP products. The normal install process would be to use the DVD supplied by SONUS to do a reinstall from scratch in the event of failure. Since we deploy our softswitches to unmanned locations, having someone manually do a rebuild and reconfiguration of the servers is not the best. We have out-of-bound access to the machines' ALOMS, so running commands from OpenBoot is not a problem.

I have looked at using puppet in combination with theforeman to provide network jumpstart installs and software configuration, but due to the way the custom SONUS DVDs were created a network jumpstart has been problematic and would require us to recreate the entire install process which would involve modifying the SONUS custom scripts which we don't feel comfortable doing.

The best solution to us would to image/clone a server and then in the event of a failure have the option to do a install of that image/clone from a local linux server. Hopefully being able to leverge DHCP and NFS. Is this possible? Should we do it a different way?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old question, but just in case you're still looking for an answer, this is possible.

Solaris has the capacity to make a 'system image' called a Flash Archive.  This is a duplicate image of a fully installed system, which has the equivalent of `sysunconfig` run against it, so there is no hostname, dns servers, etc.  All the questions answered by a `sysidcfg` file will need to be answered.  The idea behind Flash Archives is to allow you to custom jumpstart a fully installed and customized system, in a repeatable way.

Using DHCP and HTTP or NFS, you can certainly install a flash archive via jumpstart, then finish it with your sysidcfg.

For an example of what this looks like, check out this page: http://gurkulindia.com/main/2011/05/solaris-10-wanboot-flash-archive-installation-procedure-2/

The WAN boot portion is optional, but might be useful if you have widely dispersed systems.

Comment: Agreed on using a flar image, as well as looking at using WANbooting.  If you have a valid support contract, you could also consider looking to see if Ops Center will work for you.